# Add Attachment from incoming message to new outgoing message

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have an order that comes in by email several times a week with an attachment that I need to send out to be processed. The software that processes the file requires that the email  be free of signatures and text in the body.

I'm triggering the script via a rule that looks for the sender and an attachment. The script should grab a template and insert the attachment. The problem I'm having is inserting the attachment.

Here is what I have so far. Thanks for helping.

```
Sub SendLeadOrder(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\OrderTemplate.oft")

    objMsg.Attachments.Add Item.Attachments
    objMsg.Display
    'objMsg.Send

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to save the attachments to disk then reapply them to the new message.  Like this

```
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sPath As String

Set Item = ActiveInspector.currentItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\OrderTemplate.oft")

For Each objAtt In Item.Attachments
    sPath = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & objAtt.FileName
    objAtt.SaveAsFile sPath
    objMsg.Attachments.Add sPath
Next objAtt

objMsg.Display
```

Are you sure it's not easier to just forward the message and clean it up as necessary?  Like this

```
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem

Set Item = ActiveInspector.currentItem
Set objMsg = Item.Forward
With objMsg
    .To = "someone@example.com"
    .Subject = "Predifined Subject"
    .Body = vbNullString
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: I would prefer to clean it up and forward but that does not seem to work for me.  This is how I have set it up

Sub SendNewOrder(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem

Set Item = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set objMsg = Item.Forward
With objMsg
    .To = "someone@example.com"
    .Subject = "Predifined Subject"
    .Body = vbNullString
    .Display
End With
End Sub

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Is the To, Subject, or Body not changing to what you have in the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what was wrong because it wasn't displaying the mail.  By using your idea of setting the body to null I was able to use another forward email example to accomplish what I needed.  Thanks for your help.